# css page-break-avoid not working for html canvas element

Tags: css, canvas, echarts

I rendered some dynamic graphs from `echarts` library. And I added these charts to my div element using the following tag

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" id='bar-chart-1' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
    <div class="col-6" id='bar-chart-2' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
    <div class="col-6" id='bar-chart-3' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
    <div class="col-6" id='bar-chart-4' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
</div>
```

But some of the graphs appear in two pages. I want to avoid this. and write CSS as,

```css
#bar-chart-1, #bar-chart-2, #bar-chart-3, #bar-chart-4{
page-break-inside: avoid;
}

canvas{
page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

`page-break` rule is working fine for other div and images only not working with `canvas` element generated by echarts. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with bootstrap col property, not in the canvas element. For avoiding the page break rule you have to make sure following things,

1. Your element have display property `block`
2. The overflow-x should not be set `hidden`
3. The page-break rule not work with `float`, bootstrap `col` property, and `grid`

If you have the content in two column, then you must assign the page-break-inline rule at the parent `div`, something like below,

```
<div class="row" style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
    <div class="col-3" id='bar-chart-1' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
    <div class="col-3" id='bar-chart-2' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
    <div class="col-3" id='bar-chart-3' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
    <div class="col-3" id='bar-chart-4' style="width=100%; height=500px"></div>
</div>
```